# Existence of the limit of the derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, contest-math

Let $f : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable such that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=2019$ Then which of the following is correct?

A.$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ always exists but not necessarily zero.

B.$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ always exists and is equal to zero.

C.$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ may not exist.

D.$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists if $f$ is twice differentiable.

**my approach**: Let’s assume $\underset{x\to\infty}{\lim}f’(x)=L$ where , $L$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$. We see that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}$. So we use L’Hospital’s rule and get that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}+\lim_{x\to\infty}f’(x)$. So we get $L=0$. Hence option B is correct.

I have done it in this way but I want the problem to be solved also using equation damped oscillator. Can anyone give me a proof of that. Thank you

Comment: Which damped oscillator function have you tried? Try to figure out constants $a,b>0$ such that $\frac{1}{x^a} \cos(x^b) + 2019$ is as desired.

Comment: For C you can show with an example. If you use $f(x)=\sin(g(x))e^{-x}+2019$, try to find $g(x)$ such as to cancel the exponent.$$f'(x)=\cos(g(x))g'(x)e^{-x}-\sin(g(x))e^{-x}$$

Comment: While only one of A, B, or C could be correct, it is possible that D could be correct while one of A, B, or C is also correct. In fact, if A or B is correct, then so must D.

Comment: with l’hospital, you have no evidence that lim f’ / g’ would exist. So you cannot use it.

Comment: I know that is why is am asking for another proof @gnasher729